# making sense of the nmap options

Tags: networking, host, nmap

An `nmap` option I see in some [examples](http://nmap.org/docs/discovery.pdf) uses the `-sP` option, but I haven't seen this listed anywhere in their [options](http://nmap.org/book/man-briefoptions.html)  or `--help`. Is `-sP` an option you construct from the other options? If so, please explain briefly how the syntax works. If not, where is the full, complete list of options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of Nmap's options have changed over time. The most commonly-used options can be seen by running `nmap` with no options (or with `--help`). The most up-to-date list is found in the [online reference guide](http://nmap.org/book/man.html), but it only refers to the very latest version.

For the most part, older synonyms of options will still work (preserving backwards compatibility). Here's a list of some options and their older synonyms:

- `-sn` used to be `-sP`
- `-Pn` used to be `-PN` or `-P0` or for some reason `-PD`
- `-PE` used to be `-PI`
- `-oG` used to be `-oM`
- `--osscan-guess` used to be `--fuzzy`

Answer (score 2):

As (almost) always, `man NMAP(1)` has the answer. Check the `-sn (No port scan)` entry:

`In previous releases of Nmap, -sn was known as -sP`

As far as I know, all the possible options are listed in the manpage.